# How to add an activity for the contacts generated via a report?

Tags: contacts, contributions, activities, reports, activity

I have a list of contacts from a contribution report, and I would like to add an activity based on the latest result from the report. My first thought was to have a "action link" to update the activity, but don't see it there.  Is there any other way to achieve that? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would just add all the contacts to a group (you have to create the group first) and then add the activity to all the contacts in the group.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could export as csv and then adjust the csv and then use it as input for Import Activities.

Comment: Thanks. How much of a work to add a action link in the report template?

Comment: It would depend how customizable you want the activity to be but you could try it with https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterReportVar/